# Error debugging unit test in Visual Studio 2022 macos(m1)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, apple-m1, visual-studio-mac

I have this error debugging unit test in Visual Studio 2022 for macos(M1)

```
Unable to attach to CoreCLR. Unknown Error: 0x80131c3c
```

When I press in debug test, this error shows up

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: The 0x80131c3c error usually means the debugger is using a different architecture to the app being debugged. What sort of test project is this? Does it happen for a new test project? Which VS Mac version are you using? What dotnet is configured in preferences - Build and Debug - SDK Locations - .NET Core?

Comment: I reinstalled visual studio and it works! Thanks!